# Using SAS macros, is there a way to create variables with names that have spaces?

Tags: macros, sas

I'd like to use a macro to create a variable in my dataset. The variable name has spaces. Usually in SAS I would have to enclose the name with apostrophes: 'var_name'n . In macros, I've tried to mask the apostrophes using %(str):

For instance:

```
%macro test(varname);
%str(')&varname.%str('n)=""
%mend;
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `%` symbol to escape the single quote and the `%unquote` function to resolve the reference, like so:

```
%macro test(varname);
    %unquote(%str(%'&varname.%'n))="";
%mend;
```

Derived from [Sample 25076: Resolve a macro variable within single quotes](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/076.html)